# Problematic Random Forest training runtime when using formula interface

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, formula

Running the Random Forest example from http://www.kaggle.com/c/icdar2013-gender-prediction-from-handwriting/data, the following line:

```
forest_model <- randomForest(as.factor(male) ~ ., data=train, ntree=10000)
```

takes hours (not sure whether it will ever end, but the process does seems to work) .

The data set has 1128 rows and ~7000 variables.

Is it possible to estimate when the Random Forest training will finish? Can I profile R somehow to get more information?

Comment: You can run a few samples with `ntree=100` then `ntree=500` etc... And figure out how much time each takes on your computer with your number of variables, processors (if you're using parallel), etc, then plot your results and you can extrapolate the time for `ntree=10000`

Comment: is Random Forest running time is linear in terms of the amount of trees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea, to control the convergence is to use the `do.trace` for a **verbose mode**

```
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,
+                         proximity=TRUE,do.trace=TRUE)
ntree      OOB      1      2      3
    1:   8.62%  0.00%  9.52% 15.00%
    2:   5.49%  0.00%  3.45% 13.79%
    3:   5.45%  0.00%  5.41% 11.76%
    4:   4.72%  0.00%  4.88%  9.30%
    5:   5.11%  0.00%  6.52%  8.89%
    6:   5.56%  2.08%  6.25%  8.33%
    7:   4.76%  0.00%  6.12%  8.16%
    8:   5.41%  0.00%  8.16%  8.16%
 .......
```

Comment: thanks! now I can see the (very slow) progress of the forest creation when I cut the variables amount from 7000 to 3500. However for 7000 variables, I still see no output. Any further profiling suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

Found the problem, using formula in randomForest has created a tremendous performance degradation.

More on this and how to estimate random forest running time can found in:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37370/random-forest-computing-time-in-r and in http://www.gregorypark.org/?p=286

Here is final code:

```
forest_model <- randomForest(y=train$male, x=train[,-2], ntree=10000,do.trace=T)
```