# Progress bar in random forest model in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using randomForest model in R .

For large numbers of trees my program takes a long time to complete .

In "randomForest" function i can use "do.trace=TRUE" to see the real time progress .  Sample out put in real time on R console is as follows

```
ntree    OOB      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9 
100:   2.31%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  2.25% 10.81%  0.90%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
200:   1.95%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  2.25%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
300:   1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
400:   1.95%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  3.45% 
500:   1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
600:   1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
700:   1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
800:   1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
900:   1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72% 
1000:  1.78%  7.14%  2.08%  0.00%  1.69%  8.11%  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  1.72%
```

The first row (100: 2.31% ....) comes first. After 1 second it comes 2nd row and so on. I would like to modify this output .

When 1st row will come , I need to grab only "100" from the whole line and show only "100" on R console instead of showing the whole line. Similarly for rest of the rows.

[ I tried sink(). but it will not work as `sink` writes the complete output to output file ]

[I searched for `do.trace` option in randomForest function. but I lost myself  as I suspect it calls come C program; although I am not sure.]

I would like to grab the real time output on R console.

> Note : I have seen the following issues .
>
> 1. https://github.com/jni/ray/issues/33
> 2. [Problematic Random Forest training runtime when using formula interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321947/problematic-random-forest-training-runtime-when-using-formula-interface])

Comment: I saw your posting on Rhelp. Thank you for waiting a decent interval before re-posting. A that time I did try to examine the R code and decided that your hunch that these messages were coming from the underlying C code was correct. My edit was only intended to correct capitalization and make the message more in conformance with SO posting guidelines. Since at least one of the linked answers relates to the syntax of the `randomForest` call, you should post yours.

Answer (score 3):

Downloaded: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/randomForest_4.6-10.tar.gz

When looking at the C code for refRF.C (and I suspect classRF.C which is also called with `do.trace` when it's a classification problem) and then following the 'jprint' flag which is what is received by the `do.trace`-flag in the surrounding R code, we see:

```
/* print header for running output */
    if (*jprint <= *nTree) {
    Rprintf("     |      Out-of-bag   ");
    if (*testdat) Rprintf("|       Test set    ");
    Rprintf("|\n");
    Rprintf("Tree |      MSE  %%Var(y) ");
    if (*testdat) Rprintf("|      MSE  %%Var(y) ");
    Rprintf("|\n");
    }
```

And:

```
 /* Print running output. */
    if ((j + 1) % *jprint == 0) {
        Rprintf("%4d |", j + 1);
        Rprintf(" %8.4g %8.2f ", errb, 100 * errb / varY);
        if(*labelts == 1) Rprintf("| %8.4g %8.2f ",
                                  errts, 100.0 * errts / varYts);
        Rprintf("|\n");
    }
    mse[j] = errb;
    if (*labelts) msets[j] = errts;
```

It should not be particularly difficult to trim that code to the point where it is only emitting the hundredth tree notification in a form you desire.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that .

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to find either the original source code for that version of the `RandonForest` in the package Archive directory or the current version which is what would now be in  `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/`. Package versions get retired when a new version is accepted by CRAN. That's how the package distribution mechanism works.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/ where one can infer that there have been 4 versions in the last 8 years since 4.6-10 and that 4.7-2 is the current version. I don't think that I am responsible for updating that link every time there is a new version.